# vba common table expression cte operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, vba, excel, common-table-expression

I am executing a sql statement concatenated from a worksheet in Excel and returning the results to another worksheet. If I run an inline nested query the results are returned without error (although performance is much slower 3 min vs couple seconds) if I use a common table expression CTE as shown below I get run-time error '3704' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. I am using Excel 2010 and querying an Oracle 11g db. The query works fine in Toad and I seem to remember running CTE queries out of Excel against Oracle so I do not think that is the issue. I have no control over making any changes to the DB or setting this as a stored procedure. Thanks in advance for any assitance.

Full code sanitized for confidentiality:

```
Sub RefreshData()

'Turn off screen updating and alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'User cell selection when running macro
Dim iRowRef As Integer
Dim iColRef As Integer
SheetRef = ActiveSheet.Name
iRowRef = ActiveCell.Row
iColRef = ActiveCell.Column

Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 2).Value = "Start time: " & Now()

'Create connection
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If strUname = "" Then
    strUname = InputBox(Prompt:="USERNAME", Title:="Authentication", Default:=(Environ$("Username")))
End If
If strPword = "" Then
    'strPword = InputBox(Prompt:="PASSWORD", Title:="Authentication", Default:="Password")
    strPword = modPWMask.InputBoxPW("PASSWORD", "Authentication")
End If
```

***edit: Issue was with the provider in the connection string. CTE support is provider dependent. Thanks @TimWilliams

```
'Connection string
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=" & strUname & ";Password=" & strPword & ";Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = host.com)(PORT = 100))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = db_prd)))"
'Open connection
cn.Open

'Query Data Runoff
strQuery = Worksheets("SQL").Cells(2, 2).Value & UCase(Format(Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(7, 3).Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")) & Worksheets("SQL").Cells(2, 3).Value
'Send query string to clipboard
Dim DataObj3 As New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj3.SetText strQuery
DataObj3.PutInClipboard

    'Clear old data
    Worksheets("Data").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Data").Range("C20:E20").ClearContents

    'Create recordset from query
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)
```

This is the line where I am getting the error:

```
    'Paste data from record set
    Worksheets("Data").Range("C20").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Timestamp end time
Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(3, 2).Value = "Last refreshed: " & Now()

'Turn on screen updating and alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Return to starting cell
Worksheets(SheetRef).Activate
Cells(iRowRef, iColRef).Select

End Sub
```

And this is the SQL again sanitized for confidentiality:

```
with cte as
(
select
  ENTITY
  , ENDPOINT
  , case 
    when RWS = 1 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_B
    when RWS = 2 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_A
    else PCT_A end as PCT
  , SUM(case
    when RWS = 1 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then cast(BAL_B AS decimal (18,2))
    when RWS = 2 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then cast(BAL_A AS decimal (18,2))
    when RWS = 2 then cast(BAL AS decimal (18,2))
    else 0 end) as BAL
  , ROUND(SUM((case
    when RWS = 1 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then cast(BAL_B AS decimal (18,2))
    when RWS = 2 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then cast(BAL_A AS decimal (18,2))
    when RWS = 2 then cast(BAL AS decimal (18,2))
    else 0 end)
  *
  (case
    when RWS = 1 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_B
    when RWS = 2 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_A
    else PCT_A end)
  /100),2) as ADJ_BAL
from 
  SCHEMA.VIEW
  cross join (select 1 as RWS from dual  union  select 2 as RWS from dual)
where 
  AS_OF_DATE = '01-NOV-2016'
group by
  ENTITY
  , ENDPOINT
  , case
    when RWS = 1 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_B
    when RWS = 2 and ENDPOINT in (13,14) then PCT_A
    else PCT_A end
)

select sum(case
          when ENTITY = 'ENTITYA' and ENDPOINT <> 33 then ADJ_BAL
          when ENTITY = 'ENTITYB' then ADJ_BAL
          when ENTITY = 'ENTITYC' and ENDPOINT <> 33 then ADJ_BAL
          else 0
       end) as BAL_CONSOL
   , sum(case
          when ENTITY = 'ENTITYA' then ADJ_BAL
          else 0
       end) as BAL_ENTITYA
   , sum(case
          when ENTITY = 'ENTITYB' then ADJ_BAL
          else 0
       end) as BAL_ENTITYB
from cte
```

Comment: The implication is the line `cn.open` is failing and you're not checking to see if the connection in fact was opened successfully.

Comment: I can add that check but I successfully execute 2 other queries prior to the one above so I do not think that is the case. ?cn.State 1

Comment: (1) check `rs.State`, not `cn.State`  (2) check the Connection's Errors collection  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/167957

Comment: @TimWilliams that is the problem rs.State = 0. Am I correct in thinking the problem is with the SQL? If I run it with the CTE in the from statement as a nested query it works... *edit even if I explicitly open the rs using rs.Open strQuery, cn, adOpenStatic I still get rs.State = 0

Comment: Why not just convert the CTE to a nested/subquery? I know it stinks, but it should work.

Comment: The performance of the subquery is pretty bad but if I can't figure it out I might have to live with it.

Comment: Did you check the Errors collection on the Connection object?

Comment: Ability to run a CTE may be provider-dependent ?  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?617958-MS-OLEDB-Provider-for-Oracle-and-CTEs

Comment: Works for me with Provider `OraOLEDB.Oracle` and `CursorLocation = adUseClient`   Can't get it to work with the `MSDAORA.1` provider

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! Confirmed it was the provider MSDAORA. If you want to add as an answer I will mark solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with Provider  `OraOLEDB.Oracle` and

```
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

Can't get it to work with the `MSDAORA.1` provider